# Url redirection is not working for WKWebview , where as working for UIWebview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

When I am load a embedded html content using `UIWebview` 
UIWebView.loadRequest() , the page load is happening . 
Although when loading the same content using WKWebview page is not loading properly. I have checked the redirection url from `decidePolicyFor navigationAction` delegate method and they are same as `UIWebview`.
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: add your code here to be helped better